# Собор Святой Софии (Константинополь) – София Константинопольская?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Собор Святой Софии (Константинополь) можно ли назвать (и упоминается ли где-нибудь) храмом Софии **К**онстантинопольской?

> О столице «золотого века», о городе Рас, известной цитадели на границе
>   тогда ещё сербских и болгарских земель, упоминает император Юстиниан I
>   – строитель Софии Константинопольской.

О кавычках вкруг золотого века можно не рассказывать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это распространенный способ ссылки на *архитектурные сооружения* имени одной и той же святой, например, Софийский собор в Киеве - София Киевская, в Новгороде - София Новгородская. Здесь - то же самое; видовое наименование "храм" с таким названием плохо сочетается ("храм С. К." - неверно, поскольку указывает на некую "местную" святую).